# How to create random numbers in such a way that sum of the numbers should be only whole number or zero in php?

Tags: php

I am creating one algorithm for kids that will create random numbers and showing 5 numbers in each row upto 6 rows.for whole numbers it is good.But when i am taking random numbers between a negative and a positive number then there is possibility of negative result.So what should i write so that the result will be only positive number or zero irrespective of taking negative numbers? Below is my code,

```
   $Final_Array = array();
   $Final_Ansarray = array();
   for ($i = 1; $i < 31; $i++) {
    $Random_Number = mt_rand(-4,8);
    $RandVal = $Random_Number . "";
    array_push($Final_Array, $RandVal);
   }
  $Chunked_Array = array_chunk($Final_Array, 5);
  foreach ($Chunked_Array as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
        echo $value2 . "\n";
    }
    echo "|";
   }
    foreach ($Chunked_Array as $k => $subArray) {
    $Answers = array_sum($subArray);
    echo $Answers . "|";
    array_push($Final_Ansarray, $Answers);
}
```

Comment: "Whole number".. umm. do you mean integers?

Comment: This makes no sense. Why are you passing negative numbers to `mt_rand()` in the first place, if you don't want a negative result?

Comment: If you don't want negative result - why are you using `-4` in `mt_rand` function?

Comment: yes i want integers only

Comment: i want whole number as result from negative numbers also

Comment: `mt_rand` generates integers. How did you get floats then?

Comment: suppose in a row the numbers are -4,-5,-2,-5,5 and their answer is -11.So i want to choose random numbers in such a way that their sum should be positive or zero only

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$cols = 5;
$rows = 6;

$array = array();

for ($j = 0; $j < $rows; $j++)
    {
    do
        {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $cols; $i++)
            $array[$i] = mt_rand(-4, 8);
        }
    while (array_sum($array) < 0); // pass only non negative sums

    echo'sum', json_encode($array), ' = ', array_sum($array), PHP_EOL;
    }
```

Example output

```
sum[1,-1,2,8,-2] = 8
sum[1,5,5,5,-4] = 12
sum[2,7,-1,6,0] = 14
sum[8,0,-2,-1,0] = 5
sum[7,-2,8,4,2] = 19
sum[7,-4,-4,0,1] = 0
```